# Error when installing and trying to get version of SASS via Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, .bash-profile

Not sure what is going on, I was able to install git via the terminal (had to create a bash_profile).

Now I installed ruby and did install sass. However when I did `sass --version` [I got a bash error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760776/just-installed-sass-but-cant-get-its-version?noredirect=1#comment24145982_16760776)? I installed a 2nd time, samething, then I tried installing a 3rd time and got a new error:

[image]

I'm so lost, I don't know how VIM is useful, no idea what a bash_profile is.

Here is the contents of my bash_profile which I had to create in order to get the correct version of git working:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Any and all tips appreciated!

---

UPDATE, I needed to use sudo gem install sass, and was able to install it (for the 3rd time) However, I still cannot get the version of sass or do any other sass commands?

[image]

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Vim or Git: I removed the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed Ruby with Homebrew, try running `brew unlink ruby; brew link ruby`:

```
$ which sass
$ brew unlink ruby; brew link ruby
Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p0... 20 links removed
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p0... 31 symlinks created
$ which sass
/usr/local/bin/sass
```

Or add `/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin` to the path.

```
$ brew --prefix ruby
/usr/local/opt/ruby
$ stat -f%Y /usr/local/opt/ruby
../Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p0
$ export PATH=/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH
$ which sass
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/sass
```

`sudo /usr/bin/gem install sass` should install a binary of sass to `/usr/bin/sass`.

Comment: Sweet that worked! Unlinking sounded scary, so I tried the syntax below, I'm able to get Sass 3.2.9 (Media Mark) now :D also side note: I love LiveReload.... takes care of sass for me without having to tell the terminal to watch folders